# MYSQL UNION DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, left-join, union, distinct

I have two selects that I'm currently running as a UNION successfully.

```
(SELECT a.user_id,
          a.updatecontents AS city,
          b.country
   FROM userprofiletemp AS a
   LEFT JOIN userattributes AS b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
   WHERE typeofupdate='city')
UNION DISTINCT
  (SELECT a.user_id,
          c.city,
          c.country
   FROM userverify AS a
   LEFT JOIN userlogin AS b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
   LEFT JOIN userattributes AS c ON a.user_id=c.user_id
   WHERE b.active=1
     AND a.verifycity=0);
```

The results come back like this:

```
100 Melbourne Australia
200 NewYork America
300 Tokyo Japan
100 Sydney Australia
```

The catch is the query will bring duplicate user_id (in this case the 100).
The details in the first query take precedent for me and if the user_id is repeated in the second query I don't need it.

Is there a way to get a UNION to be DISTINCT on a column? in this case the user_id?
Is there a way to do the above call and not get duplicate user_id's - drop the second.
Should I re-write the query differently and not use a UNION.
Really want it as one query - I can use to SELECT's and PHP to weed out duplicate if necessary.

thx
Adam

Answer (score 38):

No. You cannot specify which exact field you need to distinct with. It only works with the whole row.

As of your problem - just make your query a subquery and in outer one `GROUP BY` `user_id`

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT a.user_id,a.updatecontents as city,b.country
FROM userprofiletemp AS a
LEFT JOIN userattributes AS b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
WHERE typeofupdate='city')

UNION DISTINCT

(SELECT a.user_id,c.city,c.country
FROM userverify AS a
LEFT JOIN userlogin AS b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
LEFT JOIN userattributes AS c ON a.user_id=c.user_id
WHERE b.active=1 AND a.verifycity=0) x
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: any chance you can give me a push in the right direction with the subquery and outer one group by user_id? haven't done that before, testing but not getting there quickly...

Comment: @Adam: updated an answer. That is how the query could look like, but have no chance to check if it is correct

Comment: If I'd like to find out what the 'x' in 'x GROUP BY user_id' means (also I've read 'a order by ...' somewhere), which docs/tutorial/link would you recommend please?

Comment: @2rec: `x` is an alias for the nested query that precedes it, since every one must have an alias.

Comment: @zerkms I see, thank you. So this could be any string I like, it doesn't matter what I put there, right?

Answer (score 4):

MySQL [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) produces distinct rows—however, all column values in the row need to be distinct. If you wish to limit the distinction to a single or a few columns, when other columns are not distinct, you can wrap the `UNION` in a sub-query and [`GROUP BY`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) the sub-query by the columns you wish to be unique.

Here I wrap the entire `UNION` in a sub-query, give it an alias, then `GROUP BY` the desired unique column:

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT a.user_id,a.updatecontents as city,b.country
FROM userprofiletemp AS a
LEFT JOIN userattributes AS b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
WHERE typeofupdate='city'

UNION

SELECT a.user_id,c.city,c.country
FROM userverify AS a
LEFT JOIN userlogin AS b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
LEFT JOIN userattributes AS c ON a.user_id=c.user_id
WHERE b.active=1 AND a.verifycity=0

) aa GROUP BY user_id;
```

If you have more than one column you'd like to include in the distinction, list them after the `GROUP BY`: such as `GROUP BY user_id, city`.

---

SIDE NOTE: since, in this case, `UNION` does not provide the desired distinction, there is no benefit to simply using `UNION`, and apparently ["`UNION ALL` is much faster than `UNION`"](https://www.iheavy.com/2013/06/13/how-to-optimize-mysql-union-for-high-speed/), therefore you can use `UNION ALL` to speed up this query.

Answer (score 2):

```
(SELECT a.user_id,a.updatecontents as city,b.country
FROM userprofiletemp AS a
LEFT JOIN userattributes AS b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
WHERE typeofupdate='city')

UNION ALL

(SELECT a.user_id,c.city,c.country
FROM userverify AS a
LEFT JOIN userlogin AS b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
LEFT JOIN userattributes AS c ON a.user_id=c.user_id
WHERE b.active=1 AND a.verifycity=0
  AND a.user_id NOT IN
      ( SELECT user_id
        FROM userprofiletemp 
        WHERE typeofupdate='city'
      ) 
);
```