# combine four table into one new table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT a.delivery_date,
       a.delivery_hour, 
       a.price as EX-ANTE, 
FROM mms_realtime_dispatch_prices_report a

  UNION ALL

SELECT b.delivery_date,
       b.delivery_hour,
       b.price as EX-POST,
FROM mms_realtime_dispatch_prices_report b

  UNION ALL

SELECT c.region,
       c.dem_rtdel,
       c.date,
FROM pub_demand_lwap c;

  UNION ALL

SELECT region,
       report,
       hour,
       SUM(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10,q11)
FROM pub_markets_bids_and_offers
WHERE delivery date=03/16/2011
GROUP BY hour
```

help! need to combine this four table into one new table no duplicate data
Can you help me in combining this four tables into one table. this is the first time i encounter this. I really need a help :(

Comment: Take a look at distinct: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: For UNION ALL to work, each of your selects should return the same number of elements and of same types..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965333/mysql-union-distinct

Comment: 1. Normalize your design. A database table IS NOT a spreadsheet! And date and time should held as a single entity

Comment: please provide an SQL fiddle or table structure

Comment: Can you suggest a SQL code for combining this 4 table into one? i really need a help.. :(

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server union works only if there is same number and type of columns return by query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your Union query right 1st I can see so many things wrong with Query At the moment,

1. Your number of columns retunred by each select arent same, Last query is returning 4 columns and other 3,
2. You are Aliasing Columns in 2nd query, it will not have any effect as Only the Column Names from very first select statement are visible in the result set.
3. Guessing from the Column names you have Different Data Types that
   you are trying to UNION. Datatypes Returned from all selects that you are using in UNION should return the same datatypes e.g

> ```
>     SELECT Column1_DataType1, Column2_DataType2, Column3_DataType3 FROM Table_Name1
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT Column1_DataType1, Column2_DataType2, Column3_DataType3 FROM Table_Name2
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT Column1_DataType1, Column2_DataType2, Column3_DataType3 FROM Table_Name3
> ```

and so on....

Once you have met all these condition then you can do something like this to eliminate duplicate rows from you result set

```
;with CTE 
AS
 (
   SELECT ID_Column, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Column1, Column2, Column3... ORDER BY ID ASC)
  FROM ( -- All of your UNION ALL Statements Can go here --)q
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: hello Sir the idea of this is to select column in that four tables then  transfer into the new table, the new table will serve as the final data which i will display. now i'm trying to use insert ignore. another problem in the selected column, i have a display data that i will get in one column then separate into new columns ex: col1: value:a|b|c will become colA| colb| colc and the equivalent value will be price of a|b|c. im having a hard time. can you help me? im a new programmer. :(