# MySQL SELECT UNION Distinct on single column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, visual-studio-2012

I have two tables for storing exchange rates in my system. the first one 
**agent_rate** is as follows.

```
ID  Currency Rate
=======================
3   GBP      0.65
4   EUR      0.70
5   JPY      57.4
```

the second table **exchange_rate** is as follows.

```
ID  Currency Rate
=======================
1   USD         1
2   ZMK       200
3   GBP       0.5
4   EUR      0.75
5   JPY      60.4
6   CHF       0.9
```

I want to select all the rows in the first table **agent_rate** and then add all the missing values of ID from the **exchange_rate** table. I wanted to use a union statement with distinct on a single column but I failed to. My current solution as follows (visual studio)

1. select from **agent_rate** table and fill rate datatable
2. set unique field i.e. ID in rate datatable
3. select and fill from **exchange_rate** table into a temp datatable
4. move records from temp datatable to rate datatable and ignore errors

the resulting table is(should be) as follows:

```
ID  Currency Rate
=======================
1   USD         1
2   ZMK       200
3   GBP      0.65
4   EUR      0.70
5   JPY      57.4
6   CHF       0.9
```

Is there a better way to do this in Sql?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL UNION DISTINCT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965333/mysql-union-distinct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table and select the agent values first if they exist, otherwise the vaolue from the exchange table

```
select coalesce(a.id, e.id) as id, 
       coalesce(a.currency, e.currency) as currency,
       coalesce(a.rate, e.rate) as rate
from exchange_rate e
left agent_rate a on a.id = e.id
```

`coalesce` returns the first non-null value in the list provided.

Comment: But if an a-row exists and it's rate column is NULL, should NULL or e.rate be returned?

Comment: Who says there is such a null column? Does not look like it in the example. Why always make things difficult if they don't have to be?

Comment: It was more of a question to the OP, to consider table definition consequences. (Like when applications with NOT IN sub-query suddenly doesn't work anymore, just because a first NULL value is there...)

Comment: Awesome! this is helpful! Accorrding to http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php . the COALESCE() function returns the first non-NULL value of a list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.